# Jsoup connection appears does not work and does not time out

Tags: java, intellij-idea, connection, jsoup

I am working with the following line of code on a project:

```
            Document d = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(3000).get();
```

I'm using an IntelliJ debugger and when I get to this line of code, the debugger disables all of it's buttons and just says "the application is running."  It does not timeout and it never throws an exception or continue.  Does anyone know why this might be happening?  If I take the following code

```
    String url = "https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/bxd/";
    Document d = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(3000).get();
    System.out.println(d);
```

and run it in the main method of a seperate class it works just fine.

Comment: Please reproduce more of the code before and just after the line in question so that we can more understand the context in which this is occurring.

Comment: I wish I could, but I can't post significant portions of my code online or else my school will count that as plagiarism.  I think the issue might be with the debugger.  Someone told it me if just kind of stops working whenever it gets to a socket.